# Unable to complete SSSD lookup to LDAP source

Tags: ldap, nss, sssd

I set up an LDAP service on a computer in my home network.  I can run ldapsearch commands from my desktop to it and they return with no problem.  What I'm unable to do is to get authentication via LDAP working.

[Note:  desktop is running the latest version of Xubuntu.]
I tried with libpam-ldap and libpam-ldapd, but got nowhere, so I found a suggestion to use SSSD.  I updated nsswitch.conf to use sss and created the sssd.conf file to point to my LDAP server.  SSSD starts successfully, but "getent passwd" doesn't return non-local users.

All the sssctl commands I've run seem to give me the expected results, e.g.

```
root@Avaux:/etc/init.d# sssctl domain-status westphalia.local
Online status: Online

Active servers:
LDAP: croxtonnas

Discovered LDAP servers:
- croxtonnas
```

And, as I said, I can run ldapsearch commands.
My only hint is the following logging information from syslog.  I've googled and found some things about these errors but nothing that solves my problem.

```
Feb  3 20:25:08 Avaux sssd[251043]: (2022-02-03 20:25:08): [be[westphalia.local]] [sbus_issue_request_done] (0x0040): sssd.dataprovider.getDomains: Error [1432158215]: DP target is not configured
Feb  3 20:25:08 Avaux systemd[1]: Started System Security Services Daemon.
Feb  3 20:25:08 Avaux systemd[1]: Starting SSSD NSS Service responder socket.
Feb  3 20:25:08 Avaux systemd[1]: Starting SSSD PAM Service responder private socket.
Feb  3 20:25:08 Avaux systemd[1]: Starting SSSD IFP Service responder...
Feb  3 20:25:08 Avaux sssd_check_socket_activated_responders[251046]: (2022-02-03 20:25:08:631047): [sssd] [main] (0x0070): Misconfiguration found for the nss responder.
Feb  3 20:25:08 Avaux sssd_check_socket_activated_responders[251046]: The nss responder has been configured to be socket-activated but it's still mentioned in the services' line in /etc/sssd/sssd.conf.
Feb  3 20:25:08 Avaux sssd_check_socket_activated_responders[251046]: Please, consider either adjusting your services' line in /etc/sssd/sssd.conf or disabling the nss's socket by calling:
Feb  3 20:25:08 Avaux sssd_check_socket_activated_responders[251046]: "systemctl disable sssd-nss.socket"
Feb  3 20:25:08 Avaux systemd[1]: sssd-nss.socket: Control process exited, code=exited, status=17/n/a
Feb  3 20:25:08 Avaux systemd[1]: sssd-nss.socket: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb  3 20:25:08 Avaux systemd[1]: Failed to listen on SSSD NSS Service responder socket.
```